# Get cart total inside an <a> html tag in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to add a custom menu element to the WordPress navigation. I'm using Woocommerce plugin as well.

I'm using below code to add the menu element and it works fine but I can't get the `get_cart_total()` showing just after the "Cart" text.

```
function add_menu_cart_wc($items, $args) {
          if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
          $items .= '<li class="menu-item">'
                  . '<a href="'. wc_get_cart_url() .'">Cart "'. get_cart_total() .'"</a>'
                  . '</li>';
          }
        return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_menu_cart_wc', 10, 2);
```

Error I'm getting is `Call to undefined function get_cart_total()`

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `get_cart_total()` defined? Should it not be `wc_get_cart_total()`?

Comment: Sure it's not `wc_get_cart_total()` seems to go nicly inline with the other function name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Got it to work by using `WC()->cart->get_cart_total()`.

Comment: Or `wc_price( WC()->cart->get_cart_total() )` to get the formatted total amount with currency.